# Can I reduce the length of the Dropbox folder name on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

My Dropbox Folder name is "Dropbox (Personal)""

[image]

That's a bit too long for me as Windows have a 255 Character File Path Limit.

Is there any way to shorten it?

("Move" only allows me to change the folder name, only its location.)

[image]

Comment: I take it you also have DropBox for Business on the computer?

Comment: @sunk818 I use the usual dropbox client. I don't believe that  DropBox for Business has a specific client.

Comment: I mean to say that you have two Dropboxes on your computer: 1) personal and 2) work. This is why your personal Dropbox says **Dropbox (Personal)** instead of just **Dropbox** ** example here: https://www.dropbox.com/help/4241

Comment: Yep two dropboxes!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign a new drive letter to `c:\users\francky\DropBox (Personal)`, you can also use the [subst](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true) command:

`subst d: "c:\users\francky\DropBox (Personal)"`

d: is the new drive letter you want to use to access that subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Move your **Dropbox (Personal)** location the root so it located at **C:\Dropbox (Personal)**

Comment: Thanks but I would like to rename "Dropbox (Personal)" to a shorter name, ideally a one-letter one like "D", to avoid hitting the 255 Character File Path Limit.

Comment: By moving from c:\users\francky to c:\ you have already saved 13 characters.